# Trouble with a NOT IN query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.customer_id, d.date_added FROM `order` d
WHERE d.customer_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT i.customer_id 
    FROM `order` i 
    WHERE i.date_added > '2015-02-15 14:00:00'
)
ORDER BY d.date_added DESC;
```

The above query should return customer_id of customers who have not ordered after 15 Feb 2015 (I think). But very first record is
`17168, 2015-08-16 17:36:00`

What am I doing wrong?

This below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.customer_id,i.date_added FROM `order` i 
WHERE i.date_added > '2015-02-15 14:00:00' 
ORDER BY i.date_added ASC;
```

returns expected result i.e. list of customer ids for orders placed after 15 Feb

P.S. customer_id can not be NULL

P.P.S.

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `order`;
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| order | CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_prefix` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `store_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `custom_field` text NOT NULL,
  `payment_firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `payment_lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `payment_company` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `payment_address_1` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `payment_address_2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `payment_city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `payment_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `payment_country` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `payment_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_zone` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `payment_zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_address_format` text NOT NULL,
  `payment_custom_field` text NOT NULL,
  `payment_method` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `payment_code` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_company` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_address_1` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_address_2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_country` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_zone` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_address_format` text NOT NULL,
  `shipping_custom_field` text NOT NULL,
  `shipping_method` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_code` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `order_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `affiliate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `commission` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `marketing_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tracking` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `currency_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `currency_code` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `currency_value` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00000000',
  `ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `forwarded_ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `accept_language` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `payment_company_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `payment_tax_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `review_requested` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  KEY `store_id` (`store_id`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `customer_group_id` (`customer_group_id`),
  KEY `payment_country_id` (`payment_country_id`),
  KEY `payment_zone_id` (`payment_zone_id`),
  KEY `shipping_country_id` (`shipping_country_id`),
  KEY `shipping_zone_id` (`shipping_zone_id`),
  KEY `order_status_id` (`order_status_id`),
  KEY `affiliate_id` (`affiliate_id`),
  KEY `marketing_id` (`marketing_id`),
  KEY `language_id` (`language_id`),
  KEY `currency_id` (`currency_id`),
  KEY `payment_company_id` (`payment_company_id`),
  KEY `payment_tax_id` (`payment_tax_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=39783 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

Comment: @Mihai The objective is show customers who have NOT ordered after 15 Feb 2015

Comment: @ypercube datetime

Comment: Exact version of mysql?

Comment: 5.6.25-73.1-log

Comment: Can you add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`order\`;` output as well? This looks like a bug.

Comment: Also, can you try running this before executing the query?: `set optimizer_switch='semijoin=off';` and tell us if you get the same unexpected/wrong results?

Comment: The query you posted looks fine. Are you sure that's exactly what you were executing?

Comment: @MartinSmith Yup, and http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/115f4/1 seems to think I am ok. But when I run the query on my database from NaviCat, I get the unexpected response.

Comment: And please add the `EXPLAIN` output as well.

Comment: Off to bed now. Gotta catch my 4 hours. Will get crackin' in the mornin'. Thanks chaps!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug. The improvements to the optimizer regarding anti-joins and subquery materialization, introduced in 5.6, seem relevant. There was a similar bug ([#73368](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73368)), related to subquery materialization but it has been fixed in 5.6.22 version.

I suggest you first, try running the query with each of the following options and check if you get the same unexpected/wrong results:

```
set optimizer_switch = 'semijoin=off';

set optimizer_switch = 'materialization=off';
```

Just noticed that it's a MyISAM table, so it's worth checking as well if it is a [corruption](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/corrupted-myisam-tables.html) issue (you can `CHECK` and/or `REPAIR` the table).

Then update your installation with the latest 5.6.26 version and check again with default options (and again with the 2 options above).

If you are still getting wrong results, [report the bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/) to MySQL, adding the query, the table `CREATE` statement, the `EXPLAIN` output and uploading a dump of the table as well, so they can reproduce it. If you can reproduce the bug with a smaller table (just the 2-3 columns and a few rows) would be much better than a 50-column and a thousands rows table.

Answer (score 3):

**Switch to NOT EXISTS**:

Don't use `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`, it optimizes poorly, even with "materialization".  Instead, use `LEFT JOIN .. IS NULL` or `NOT EXISTS`.  That should also obviate the need for `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT  d.customer_id, d.date_added
    FROM  `order` d
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  `order`
            WHERE  customer_id = d.customer_id
              AND  date_added > '2015-02-15 14:00:00' 
      )
    ORDER BY  d.date_added DESC;
```

To make my subquery run *much* faster, change

```
KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`)
```

to the "composite" key:

```
KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`, date_added)
```

**GROUP BY**

Well, maybe you did need the `DISTINCT`, but it will not give you one line per user.  `GROUP BY` can:

```
SELECT  d.customer_id,      -- no dups here
        MAX(d.date_added)   -- last order date
    FROM  `order` d
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  `order`
            WHERE  customer_id = d.customer_id
              AND  date_added > '2015-02-15 14:00:00' 
      )
    GROUP BY  d.customer_id
    ORDER BY  MAX(d.date_added) DESC;
```

**HAVING**

Even simpler (assuming I have not lost your semantics), is

```
SELECT  customer_id,
        MAX(date_added) AS last_order
    FROM  `order`
    GROUP BY  customer_id
    HAVING    last_order < '2015-02-15 14:00:00'
    ORDER BY  last_order DESC;
```

**Unrelated schema recommendations**:

- The `payment_*` and `shipping_*` fields are probably repeated both within a row and between rows.  I assume, for example, you don't have the user retype all that stuff each time they order something?  Suggest you 'normalize' that collection of fields into a new table.
- Also, having `company` and `company_id` (ditto for `zone`) makes no sense.  Put the lengthy name in another table.
- For `company_id`, use the 2-letter standard instead of the 4-byte INT.  (And then make it `CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii` to avoid the unnecessary utf8.)
- I see no composite indexes; I suspect you would benefit from some others.  Look at your other `SELECTs` together with [my index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: the payment_* and shipping_* makes sense because are the easiest and more simple method to have the correct data in the database. should you update the delivery address of the customer record after the order, the order will still have the proper data. there are other options but this one imho is effective with low effort.